# jquery offset(); doesn't work

Tags: jquery, offset

I've got this code:

```
$("#pile2_3").click(function() {

          alert($("#cardSelected").offset());

});

<div id="cardSelected"></div>
```

and it keeps returning [Object object] value in alert box, what can be possibly wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The offset is represented by two numbers, so jQuery returns an object which contains those two values as properties... Read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$().offset()` returns an object. However, you need to access it's properties:

```
$("#cardSelected").offset().top;

$("#cardSelected").offset().left;
```

Or `console.log( $("#cardSelected").offset() )` to see all available props.

Answer (score 2):

`.offset()` is working just fine. It returns an object that looks something like this:

```
{left: 42, top: 9000}
```

**It's `alert()` that sucks.** It always converts its arguments to strings, and `Object.prototype.toString`is a function which basically just returns the string `[object Object]`.

## Use `console.log()` for debugging, not `alert()`.

Comment: True, but iOS's console will still return [Object Object] !

Answer (score 0):

The offset function returns an object with left and top properties on it.

Try the following:

```
var offset = $("#cardSelected").offset();
alert('Left: ' + offset.left + ', Top: ' + offset.top);
```

Comment: I see, I guess i know where's the problem. Totally dump question, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

offset is an object.

```
 var offset = $("#cardSelected").offset();
 alert(offset.left);
```